# How validate a sum of list in AngularJS to a particular value?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a list containing amounts under categories as below

```
[{Category:'a',amount:0,sum:1000},
 {Category:'a',amount:300,sum:1000},
{Category:'b',amount:200,sum:2000},
{Category:'b',amount:500,sum:2000},
{Category:'b',amount:200,sum:2000}
]
```

This list is dynamically generated i.e I can have any number of categories and amounts under the categories. I am listing the above using `ng-repeat` where `amount` will be `input box`.Now I have to validate the fields in such a way that the sum of the inputs should be equal to the given sum other wise display error or redden the boxes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your category object array is available in the controller as `$scope.categories`, you can add a watcher to it.

```
$scope.$watch('categories', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var sum = newValue.map(function(category) {
        return category.sum;
    });
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me directives are the perfect place to write validations but here in your case, there are multiple input box so it would be better to write in the controller or if you gonna use this logic in multiple place, just put it in the service.

Suppose your inputbox is bounded with object in the following manner-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amounts.amount1">
<input type="text" ng-model="amounts.amount2">
.
.
<input type="text" ng-model="amounts.amountN">
```

Now you can either put a watcher in the controller to validate sum or on the final submission, you can validate the input

Lets take validation on final submission

```
function validateInput(){
    var tempSum= 0;
    for(var i in scope.amounts){
      tempSum += scope.amounts[i].amount;
    }
    return tempSum >1000 ? false : true;
}


function submit(){

    if(validateInput()){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        alert('sum exceeds 1000');
    }
}
```

Well watcher should be least preference of a developer but if you need to validate instantly, your code should be like this

```
scope.$watch('amounts', function(){
    var tempSum= 0;
    for(var i in amounts){
        tempSum += amounts[i+1].amount;
    }
    return tempSum >1000 ? smFunctionToShowErrorOrDisableSubmitButton() : true;
 }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor blur from the text box, create one function and call it.
[Fiddler Link](https://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/Lfrmraw7/)

```js
angular.module("sampleApp", []).controller("sampleController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {Category:'a',amount:0,sum:1000},
      {Category:'a',amount:300,sum:1000},
      {Category:'b',amount:200,sum:2000},
      {Category:'b',amount:500,sum:2000},
      {Category:'b',amount:200,sum:2000}
    ];
  
    $scope.errorLogs = [];
  
    $scope.totalAmount = function(item) {
     var convertNumber = function (val1) {
       return isNaN(parseInt(val1))? 0 : parseInt(val1);
      };
      
      var filterVal = _.filter($scope.items, function(value){
          return value.Category == item.Category
   });
      var amount = _.reduce(filterVal, function(val1, val2) {       
          return convertNumber(val1.amount) + convertNumber(val2.amount);
   });
      return amount;
    };
  
    $scope.checkAmount = function (item) {      
      if($scope.totalAmount(item) > item.sum) {
        $scope.errorLogs.push(item);
      } else {
        var index = $scope.errorLogs.indexOf(item);
        if (index !== -1) {
          $scope.errorLogs.splice(index,1);
        }
      }
    };
});
</div>
```

Comment: Here if I leave the 2nd input box of a blank and I enter amount in 1st box that exceeds the sum still its not working

Comment: @saikatmukherjee, Check it now, new code it is working fine now. sorry about old code. Thanks for your reply. :-)